# Generic, catch-all term for "power user"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm stumped labeling a class of characters who use unconventional weapons and tactics for self-defense / combat. Since I'm looking for a title, a noun would be preferred. However, I can see utility in a fitting adjective used to describe the classification rather than a title if it’s more apt.

When I say "power user" I mean any kind of spell caster (be it magical or technological), shapeshifter (werewolf or doppelgänger), or superhero, mutant, or even the force wielding half of a Jedi.

Can anyone offer any label, title, or adjectve which could fit for any of these types of characters?

Example sentence:

> When I say _______, I mean any kind of spell caster (be it magical or technological), shapeshifter (werewolf or doppelgänger), or superhero, mutant, or even the force wielding half of a Jedi.

Examples of coinciding classes:

- Marksman: a person proficient in ranged weaponry, such as bows and guns.
- Fighter: a person proficient in melee combat and weaponry, such as martial arts and daggers.
- Sentinel: a person proficient with shields and deflecting stacks directed at himself and others.
- Saboteur: a person proficient with stealth and explosives.
- "power-user": a person proficient in the use of advanced technology, the supernatural, occult, or schools of magic.

Comment: What do you mean by a "technological spell caster"?

Comment: Seems like a better question for [Arcade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) or [Role-playing Games](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: When I say "technological spell caster" I think of Marvel's Ironman. He's not really a wizard or mage in any traditional sense, but he's basically using "technology" in place of "magic" to explain away his laser bolts and flying powers. And they already booted this question from role playing games :(

Comment: What other classes of characters do you already have? That might rule out some answers. And it might give ideas for the group mentioned.

Comment: Regarding the 3 close votes so far with reason "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered." What is the precise concern here? Is it because there is no example sentence; if so the second paragraph could be tweaked into one but that seems like nitpicking as OP's requirement seems clear?

Comment: @k1eran: I believe that the OP’s desire is far from clear, and the thought of rolling back your edit crossed my mind. For one thing, part of the “include information on how it will be used” issue is to clarify the desired part of speech.  I can’t tell from the question whether the OP wants a noun or an adjective. Your edit has tilted the table toward nouns, without any indication from the OP that that is what he wants — to the contrary, he has accepted your answer, which suggests an adjective.

Comment: @Scott Hopefully the OP will return to confirm his intentions (or better still edit question himself) My edit was after the question was closed, with the aim of rescuing it !

Comment: @k1eran: Well, [your previous comment](/q/362467/26083#comment843700_362467) made it apparent that you were trying to salvage the question.  And of course we all hope that the OP will improve the question. But he (or she?) is a brand new user who has accepted an answer and hasn’t been active for two days, so I’m not holding my breath.

Comment: @pipknuts: Thanks for coming back and clarifying the question. If you want a noun — I guess “wizard” is too specific?  How about “mage” ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mage): A magician or learned person) or [“magus”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magus)?  Or perhaps “transcendental”, which is defined in the dictionary as an adjective ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transcendental): Relating to a spiritual realm; [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcendental): supernatural), but you could use as a noun if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps **preternatural**  would fit?

Penn State Press publishes a [journal](http://www.psupress.org/journals/jnls_Preternature.html) using that terminology.

> **Preternature** provides an interdisciplinary, inclusive forum for the study of topics that stand in the liminal space between the known world and the inexplicable. The journal embraces a broad and dynamic definition of the preternatural that encompasses the weird and uncanny—**magic, witchcraft, spiritualism, occultism, esotericism, demonology, monstrophy, and more**, recognizing that the areas of magic, religion, and science are fluid and that their intersections should continue to be explored, contextualized, and challenged.

Comment: I really like this use of the word "preternatural" and the stated mission of the Penn State journal.  I like it even more when considering the Latin meaning "beyond nature" -- from *praeter*, "beyond".  That should be inclusive enough for magic and technology in this given usage.  However, I'm inclined toward a **noun** to fit the OP's request.  I suppose we could call someone "a preternatural", making this serve as a noun.  "**Preternaturalist**" is a mouthful; maybe clunky by some tastes.  Thoughts?

Comment: @RandyTillman Preternaturals is indeed used by at least one author as a noun - though admittedly I can't find it in a dictionary with that usage ! See https://www.amazon.co.uk/Blood-Lust-Preternaturals-Book-1/dp/0981943608

Comment: That's precedent enough for me!  I'm interested to hear @pipknuts weigh in.

Comment: Preternatural... A mouthful, I agree, but apt! I may use this as a defining term for a simpler and more colloquial noun, such as "Adept". In such a case, does anyone think "adept" is too vague a representation of "preternatural"?

Comment: I believe that the word *adept* is good, but it might be seen as too *specific* — [Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) has popularized that word as meaning, essentially, wizard or magic-user. In his stories, the adepts are all humans; werewolves and unicorns (who are also shape-shifters) are not considered adepts.